# Происхождение слова "зубр"

Tags: этимология

Почему лесной бык называется зубром? У него нет выдающихся зубов, за которые он мог бы получить такое название. Или оно происходит от другого слова?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Название лесного быка действительно происходит от слова "зуб". Но дело совсем не в его зубах.
В старорусском языке словом "зуб" обозначались многие острые предметы, в том числе и рога. Таким образом, животное получило название за наличие у него острых рогов. Причем слово "зубр" изначально было краткой формой прилагательного, описывающего животное. По аналогии со словами "быстр", "добр".

Comment: Рогатый - зубрый? Какая прелесть!

Comment: Здесь очень сомнительно появление "зубр" из "зуб". Откуда Р? В добр и быстр - "р" корневой.

Comment: Прилагательное "добрый" как раз образовано с помощью вставки (суффикса) "р" от слова "доба". Подобных примеров немало: острый (от "ость"), бодрый (от той же основы, что и "бдеть"), старый (от той же основы, что и "стать"), мокрый (от той же основы, что и "мокнуть"),  хитрый (от той же основы, что и "хватать", "похитить"), пёстрый (от той же основы, что и "писать").

Интересно тут слово "добро", потому что это субстантивированное прилагательное. По такой же модели возникло и слово "зубр". Сравним: доба -> добрый -> добро (каково?) и зуб -> зубрый (то есть рогатый, острый) -> зубр (каков?).